# Hadoop..how to calculate the hash of input split

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to calculate the sha256 hash of the input split and the output of  mapper should be

(key, value) where key is the location of start of the block
and value is the sha256 hash of the complete block..

My REQUIREMENT is to read the complete Input Split as One record.

here is what i have done so far.. (I have taken block size as 100 kb)..Have not worked on the Value part of the key,value. Right not just outputting 1

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
      OutputCollector <LongWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

     LongWritable key_offset = new LongWritable();
     String line = value.toString();
     long block = 0;
     if (count == 0) {
       key_offset = key;
       block = key_offset.get();
       block = block / 100000;
       count++;
     }
     output.collect(new LongWritable(block), one);
```

Comment: Input is a file..the contents and the format doesn't matter. Only thing matters is to compute hash for complete input split and then output of the mapper should me (block_offset, block_hash)

Comment: I am using this to compute a Hash Tree for files..so mapper is calculating the hashes for the leaf nodes

Comment: You need a custom input format to access the raw binary data

Comment: Does your requirement include handling different split sizes? Your code is written to the old API. Can you use the new API as well?

Answer (score 0):

Can you amend the [WholeFileInputFormat](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=WholeFileInputFormat&source=bl&ots=IiezPncCQs&sig=Qtt8-kA15wnnSs_fk86N-u2G3JE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1PHPT-mdNcyH0QGRy_jNDQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=WholeFileInputFormat&f=false) from the **Hadoop - The definitive guide** so that rather than passing the entire file contents as a BytesWritable value, you calculate the SHA256 and pass that as the value? You should just need to amend the WholeFileRecordReader.next() method replacing the IOUtils.readFully with some method for calculating the SHA256 of the file bytes - maybe something like:

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/